# using bash and rawdata, make a new data

Tags: string, bash, awk

raw data corpus, and it is like below.

```
CT check
EPT check
Dental insurance.
```

and I have a prononciation file for corpus like below.

```
...
CT  kh eo t eu
CT  kh eo l2 t eu
CT  kh eo d2
CT  kh o t eu
CT  kh o l2 t eu
CT  kh o d2
check tʃ e k
...
...
EPT i p i t i
...
...
```

Now I want to make new prononciation file for original corpus like below.

```
CTcheck  kh eo t eu tʃ e k
CTcheck  kh eo l2 t eu tʃ e k
CTcheck  kh eo d2 tʃ e k
CTcheck  kh o t eu tʃ e k
CTcheck  kh o l2 t eu tʃ e k
CTcheck  kh o d2 tʃ e k
EPTcheck i p i t i tʃ e k
Dentalinsurance ...
```

I try to do it, but I am not good at bash, 
its difficult.

could anybody please help me.

below is by trial, but its seemed not good.

```
mkdir -p $srcdir/temp
while read line; do 
    echo $line | sed s/" "//g > $srcdir/temp/line.txt
    for word in $line; do
         echo -e `grep $word $srcdir/lexicon | grep -v "[[:graph:]]$word\|$word[[:graph:]]"` | wc -l >> $srcdir/temp/word.txt
         echo -e `grep $word $srcdir/lexicon | grep -v "[[:graph:]]$word\|$word[[:graph:]]"| cut -f2- ` >> $srcdir/temp/word.txt             
    done

    #rm $srcdir/temp/word.txt
    exit 1
done < $srcdir/uniqWordList.mixed.normed > $srcdir/mixedlexicon
```

thanks and regard/

Comment: Is there just one occurrence of "check" in the second code block?

Comment: It will be more clear if you could put more clear examples(eg--> remove dots from samples and place sample data in there for better understanding of question), kindly do add samples and let us know once done.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following `awk` tested with provided samples only.

```
awk '
FNR==1{
  count++
}
count==1{
  a[$1]=$1 $2
  b[$2]=(b[$2]?b[$2] OFS:"")$1
  next
}
($1 in b) && count==2{
  val=$0
  sub(/[^ ]* +/,"",val)
  num=split(b[$1],array," ")
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    c[array[i]]=val
  }
}
count==3 && !($1 in b){
  old=$1
  $1=a[$1]
  print $0,c[old]
}
'  Input_file1  Input_file2  Input_file2
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                               ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==1{                             ##Checking condition if it is first line then do following.
  count++                           ##incrementing variable count value with 1 whenever cursor comes here.
}                                   ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==1 condition here.
count==1{                           ##Checking condition if count==1 then do following.
  a[$1]=$1 $2                       ##Creating array a whose index is $1 and value is $1 $2 of current line.
  b[$2]=(b[$2]?b[$2] OFS:"")$1      ##Creating an array named b whose index is $2 and value is $1 and keep concatenating its own value here.
  next                              ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}                                   ##Closing BLOCK for count==1 condition here.
($1 in b) && count==2{              ##Checking condition ig $1 is NOT in array b and count value is 2 then do following.
  val=$0                            ##Creating variable val whose value is current line.
  sub(/[^ ]* +/,"",val)             ##Substituting everything till first space in variable val here.
  num=split(b[$1],array," ")        ##Using split of awk to split array b value with index $1 to array named array here.
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){              ##Running a for loop from i=1 to till value of num.
    c[array[i]]=val                 ##Creating an array c whose index is array[i] and value is variable val here.
  }                                 ##Closing BLOCK for; for loop here.
}                                   ##Closing BLOCK for $1 in b condition here.
count==3 && !($1 in b){             ##Checking condition if count is 3 and $1 is NOT in array b then do following.
  old=$1                            ##Creating variable old whose value is $1 of current line.
  $1=a[$1]                          ##Setting $1 value as array a value with index $1 here.
  print $0,c[old]                   ##Printing current line with array c with index old here.
}                                   ##Closing BLOCK for count==3 && !($1 in b) condition here.
' file1 file2 file2                 ##Mentioning Input_file names here.
```

Answer (score 0):

Type something like this:

```
#! /bin/bash

op=/tmp/old_prononciation

cat > $op <<EOF
...
CT  kh eo t eu
CT  kh eo l2 t eu
CT  kh eo d2
CT  kh o t eu
CT  kh o l2 t eu
CT  kh o d2
check tʃ e k
...
...
EPT i p i t i
...
...
EOF

check="$(sed -n 's/^check\(.*\)/\1/p' $op)"

for type in CT EPT; do
  sed -n "s/^$type \(.*\)/${type}check \1$check/p" $op
done
```